# Topological equivalence for an irregular shape to another (equivalent) shape

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

My last exposure to topology was almost a year ago and that was at an undergraduate level - Nonetheless, I have grown to be comfortable with topology.

I am currently doing a research with a visiting scholar and would like to know if there exists a theorem or lemma that would enable us to determine if

> 1) given a respective subset S of space in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, does there  exists a space T in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that is topologically equivalent to this space?
>
> 2) Now, suppose that there exists randomly assigned fixed number of points along the boundary of the space S. The randomly assigned fixed number of points along the boundary of the space S is a random variable with a corresponding probability distribution.

Is there a lemma or theorem that would allow us to determine the probabilities of points under a map?

Any help is appreciated.

Tangent: Can this same question be posted on math overflow?

Comment: 1)  Take any homeomorphism $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ (there are plenty of them).

Comment: 2) I'm afraid I don't know what you're asking.